# elasticsearch java api InternalDateHistogram.Bucket type is not visible

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I process a response which includes datehistogram ,

so I made List but, this type is not visible,

I think this happens because 'org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.histogram.InternalDateHistogram' -> inner class Bucket is defined as a static class (not a public);

What should I do?

Can I modify class file in elasticsearch-1.4.1.jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to cast it to a Histogram and use that. Something like this if `aggr` is your `Aggregation`:

```
String name = ((Histogram) aggr).getName();
List<? extends Histogram.Bucket> bucketList = ((Histogram) aggr).getBuckets();
for (Histogram.Bucket bucket : bucketList) {
    // do whatever
}
```